# using streamlit session state

Tags: python, streamlit

I'm struggling with streamlits call back function. (I think that is what I should be using)
On the main page, I can drop an excel file in which will show system one.
Then on page One, I'd like to use the same uploaded file that is on the main page without having to drop the same file in again. The idea is to have five pages in the end reading from one file on the Main page.

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pyautogui


if st.sidebar.button("Reset Page"):
    pyautogui.hotkey("ctrl", "F5")
st.image('https://wallpapercave.com/wp/9WBdkYu.jpg')
st.title('Excel Drag and Drop')
uploaded_file = st.file_uploader('Please upload your Excel File')

if uploaded_file:
    df = pd.read_excel(uploaded_file)

    st.subheader('System Three Selections')

    df.drop(df[df["Country"] == "South Africa"].index, inplace=True)
    df = df.drop('Date', axis=1)

    df.replace('-', 0, inplace=True)
    df["Win Result"] = df["Win Result"].replace(["L"], -1)
    df["True Odds"] = np.where(df["BSP"].ne(0), df["BSP"].sub(1), 0)
    df["ProfitLoss"] = np.where(df["Win Result"].eq(-1), df["Win Result"], df["True 
    Odds"])

    df.replace('-', 0, inplace=True)


    df.loc[df['Win Result'] ==  0, 'True Odds'] = 0

    df.replace('-', 0, inplace=True)

    df.loc[df['BSP'] == 0, 'ProfitLoss'] = 0
    df.loc[df['Win Result'] == 0, 'ProfitLoss'] = 0
    df = df[(df['Country'] == 'United Kingdom') &
            (df['WFF Rank'] == 1) &
            (df['OR'] >= 100) &
            (df['BSP'].between(1.5, 30))
    ]
    df.loc["Total", "ProfitLoss"] = df.ProfitLoss.sum()


    st.write(df)

Page 1

import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pyautogui

st.set_page_config (layout="wide")

if st.sidebar.button("Reset Page"):
    pyautogui.hotkey("ctrl", "F5")
st.image('https://wallpapercave.com/wp/9WBdkYu.jpg')
st.title ('Excel Drag and Drop')
uploaded_file = st.file_uploader('Please upload your Excel File')

if uploaded_file:
    df = pd.read_excel(uploaded_file)

    st.subheader('System Two Selections')
    df['Last Form'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Last Form'].replace({'U': '', 'C': '', 'B':'', 'D': '',
                                                             'F': '', '-': 0, 'P': '', 'R': '',
                                                             'S': '', 'V': ''}), errors='coerce')
    df.drop(df[df["Country"] == "South Africa"].index, inplace=True)
    df = df[~df['Venue'].isin(['Kempton', 'Kilbeggan', 'Kilarney', 'Leicester', 'Leopardstown', 'Limerick',
                               'Aintree'])]
    df = df[~df['Race Distance'].isin(['1m 6f 17', '1m 6y'])]
    #df = df.drop('Date', axis=1)

    df.replace('-', 0, inplace=True)
    df["Win Result"] = df["Win Result"].replace(["L"], -1)
    df["True Odds"] = np.where(df["BSP"].ne(0), df["BSP"].sub(1), 0)
    df["ProfitLoss"] = np.where(df["Win Result"].eq(-1), df["Win Result"], df["True Odds"])
    df.loc[df['Win Result'] == 0, 'True Odds'] = 0
    df.replace('-', 0, inplace=True)

    df.loc[df['BSP'] == 0, 'ProfitLoss'] = 0
    df.loc[df['Win Result'] == 0, 'ProfitLoss'] = 0
    df = df[(df['Country'] == 'United Kingdom') &
            (df['WFF Rank'] == 1) &
            (df['Last Form'].between(0, 3, inclusive=False)) &
            (df['Class Change'] >= 0) &
            (df['Improving Horse'] == 'Y') &
            (df['RDB Rating'] >= 140) &
            (df['Age'] <= 7) &
            (df['Runner Count'] <= 20) &
            (df['RDB Rank'] == 1)


            ]
    df.loc["Total", "ProfitLoss"] = df.ProfitLoss.sum()

    st.write(df)

    st.download_button(label='Download System 2', data=df.to_csv(), mime='text/csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

Implementing streamlit's session state will solve this for you.  Here's one way to implement:

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pyautogui


if st.sidebar.button("Reset Page"):
    pyautogui.hotkey("ctrl", "F5")
st.image('https://wallpapercave.com/wp/9WBdkYu.jpg')
st.title('Excel Drag and Drop')
uploaded_file = st.file_uploader('Please upload your Excel File')

if uploaded_file:
    df = pd.read_excel(uploaded_file)
    st.session_state['uploaded_file'] = df.copy()


## Then on page two, read file as follows:


if 'uploaded_file' in st.session_state.keys():
   df = st.session_state['uploaded_file']
else:
   st.error("Please upload file on main page")
```